# How do I select element that is in Nth place in the number of entries from SQL table?

Tags: sql, select

I have a table like this one:

```
ID  | DATE 
1 | 21.10.2019
2 | 13.10.2019
1 | 01.01.2019
1 | 03.02.2017
2 | 07.06.2019
4 | 09.03.2015
4 | 05.04.2019
1 | 11.02.2019
```

I want to find the ID that is in second place in the number of entries for 2019. Is there any way to do it using SELECT request? Any help is appreciated a lot

Comment: Which column defines the order? And what DBMS are you using?

Comment: What results do you want?  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find the ID that is in second place in the number of entries for 2019.

This should do what you want:

```
select t.id
from t
where t.date >= '2019-01-01' and t.date < '2020-01-01'
group by t.id
order by count(*) desc
offset 1 fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support `offset`/`fetch`.  You can do something similar in any database.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the database supports `ROW_NUMBER`, So i am writing below based on `MSQSQL`, since you dint specify the `DBMS`.

```
SELECT ID, DATE 
FROM
(
     SELECT ID, DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
     FROM tbl
     WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2019
)X WHERE RN = 2
```

**Updated**

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID,COUNT(ID)
FROM tbl
WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2019
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC
```

Comment: I think that I didn't write my question correctly, so that's not what I'm looking for..

Comment: I mean your code technically returns me the second row, that's correct. But what I am looking for is the ID that repeats the second biggest number of times in the selected for 2019 data. I am sorry that I didn't specify that..
P.S. Any DBMS is fine

Comment: @MyMan . . . Because this does not fetch the "second row", I am baffled at how it is either upvoted or accepted.

Comment: In the comment he dint mention that second row and he wants only most used id in 2019.